# How to use scss with css modules / postcss inside components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, postcss, css-modules

I'm failing to figure out how to setup my webpack in order to be able and use scss modules inside my components like:

`import styles from './ComponentStyles.scss'`

So far I tried configuring webpack to use `sass-loader` alongside `postcss-loader` but had no luck:

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
      'isomorphic-style-loader',
      'css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]',
      'postcss-loader',
      'scss-loader'
    ]
  }
```

Note [isomorphic-style-loader](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader) is a library I use instead of `style-loader` due to server rendering requirements, in its github page docs they actually use postcss-loader with .scss extension, but in my case scss is not compiled if I follow their example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do some tinkering myself, but eventually landed on the following

**package.json**

```
"autoprefixer": "^6.3.1",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"node-sass": "^3.8.0",
"sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
"style-loader": "^0.13.0"
```

**webpack config**

```
...
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
...

const config = {
    ...
    postcss: [
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        })
    ],
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/bundle.css'),
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!postcss!sass')
            }
        ]
    }
    ...
};
```

**bootstrap.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';
import style from './scss/style.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('my-app')
);
```

For those interested: what's happening here is `bootstrap.jsx` is the webpack entry point, and by importing our raw `scss` file (via relative path), we tell webpack to include it during the build process.

Also, since we've specified a `loader` for this file extension in our configuration (`.scss`), webpack is able to parse `style.scss` and run it through the defined loaders from right to left: `sass --> post-css --> css`.

We then use `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to pull the compiled CSS out from `bundle.js`, where it would normally reside, and place it in a location (`css/bundle.css`) relative to our output directory.

Also, using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` is optional here, as it will simply extract your CSS from bundle.js and plop it in a separate file, which is nice if you utilize server-side rendering, but I also found it helpful during debugging, since I had a specific output location for the `scss` I was interested in compiling.

If you're looking to see this in action, here's a small boilerplate that uses it: https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate